# How to get better suggestion(spelling) on Yahoo BOSS?

Tags: yahoo-boss-api

I have been using Yahoo BOSS for little time.  It is an easy API for search but spelling suggestion support is really not that robust.  Do folks around here have any idea of getting better spelling suggestion on BOSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you originally asked your question it looks like they added a "Spelling Service".

http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/Spelling_Suggest.html

Give it a look to see if it will accomplish what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately even a couple of years later, the spelling suggestions on the Yahoo BOSS API are very basic and not that useful :(

I compared the results -on single word queries- from the BOSS API to what you see in Google (did you mean ____?) for 100 random english words with a computer generated spelling error in them. Google guessed them right 98% of the time. Yahoo only 2%.